# WTForm i array - UnboundField FormField

Tags: python, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am a beginner in using WTForms and Python.
I have got a problem with the aggregation of WTForm in a dict or list, rendering through jinja2. 
For example :

```
class CJanuary(Form):
    nr          = int(12)
    netto       = DecimalField(u'Salary netto',         default = 0, places = 2)
    brutto      = DecimalField(u'Salary brutto',        default = 0, places = 2)    

class InputMonthlyForm(Form):
    january = FormField(CJanuary)
    months  = [FormField(CJanuary)]
```

If I render it as below:

```
{{form.january.netto}}
```

In this case everything is ok, I get source:

```
<input id="january-netto" name="january-netto" type="text" value="0.00">
```

But if I try render from list:

```
{{form.months[0].netto}}
```

in source I get nothing.

Checking what is in the list:

```
{{form.months[0]}}
```

I get:

```
<UnboundField(FormField, (<class 'apps.placowy.forms.InputMonthlyForm.CJanuary'>,), {})>
```

I have searched the internet but I can not find any solution.
Is it maybe not possible to aggregate WTForm in an array?

Comment: But why in the name of God do you need to put a formfield in a list?

Comment: Be able to iterate at mounths in template? Why you involve this with god

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `FieldList` instead of list:

```
class CJanuary(Form):
    nr          = int(12)
    netto       = DecimalField(u'Salary netto',         default = 0, places = 2)
    brutto      = DecimalField(u'Salary brutto',        default = 0, places = 2)    

class InputMonthlyForm(Form):
    january = FormField(CJanuary)
    months  = FieldList(FormField(CJanuary))
```

Comment: No, it works only for two items, if i try add three items a get: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 109, in __init__
Display the sourcecode for this frameOpen an interactive python shell in this framefor v in self.validators:
TypeError: 'UnboundField' object is not iterable